# Svelte template syntax: How can I target nested DOM elements inside an html expression with css?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using svelte to create a blog about cooking. I am getting data from a CMS that is returning HTML. I know that part of that html will be an unordered list. I'd like to style that list but my attempts are not working.

Here is my div.

[image: Svelte Template]

Here is my css selector.

[image: Svelte css selector]

And finally here is the DOM just to be sure that it's outputting what I expect.

[image: DOM output]

Is there a different way to approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? `:global()` https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style

```html
<script>
    const cmsData = "<ul><li>hey</li></ul>"
</script>

<div class="content">
    {@html cmsData}
</div>

<style>
    .content :global(ul) {
        color: red;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: Hey, this worked exactly as intended. I was a little afraid that this wouldn't be scoped to it's page but that doesn't seem to be the case. I put an unordered list inside a div with the same class name on a different page and the styles didn't apply. Perfect. Thanks! Now I know about :global.